# Android RelativeLayout alignTop doesn't work

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to use alignTop attribute in a RelativeLayout in order to set a text to right of a profile picture - aligned to picture's top.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Home fragment layout -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.coapps.pico"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_dark_green"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- title layout -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_fragment_title" >

        <!-- profile picture -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_home_profile_picture"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_profile_picture"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/test_pic" />

        <!-- user name -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fragment_home_profile_picture"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment_home_profile_picture"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="Roi Mozer"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks in the preview (and the same in the phone):

As you can see the name center is aligned to picture's top - don't know why..
[image]

**How can i set them both to be in the same line ?**

**UPDATE:**
When i changed the layout height to a given height (and not wrap content) it does work...

Comment: why do you need 2 relative layouts?

Comment: i will need in the future.. this is just the start of my layout design...

Comment: @AsafNevo : have you tried `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in both views instead of             `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fragment_home_profile_picture"` in TextView ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes and it works, but i need the profile picture to be aligned to parent vertical center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be in your image or background. I tested with another image and both are aligned along the tops.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.coapps.pico"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- title layout -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_fragment_title"
    >

    <!-- profile picture -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home_profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/falcao_large"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

    <!-- user name -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fragment_home_profile_picture"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment_home_profile_picture"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Roi Mozer"

        android:textSize="30sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

I think problem is image background. The text align to top of background

Comment: butvyou tested it aligned top. i needed the picture to be center vertical and the text aligned to picture's top

Comment: If you mean center-vertical in screen. Move `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` from `fragment_home_profile_picture` to `relativeLayout1`

Comment: you didnt understand me.. you can read my qustion again - you will see what i ment..

Comment: I can't understand what you intend to. I used your xml, I only deleted the background drawables and used a image i have. Not used `layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Comment: but according your image,both profile pic abd text are aligned to parent's top. my intent was to make the profile picture centered vertical and relativly to that - align the text to top of that picture. as you can see in my image - the picture is centered vertical but the test is aligned to parent's top. and that my problen and question

Comment: `... picture centered vertical` with respect to what??

Comment: I post new picture with background add.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

Add padding to the textView,

Comment: that's the easiest way, but the wrong approach (for my understanding at least).. your way will not work in every screen resolution..

Comment: but it will work with most of the screens. thats the best solution as far my knowledge is :) cheers

Comment: i would have used it if there was no alignTop attribute, cheers mate :)