# Negative margin not work correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to set a negative top margin to view, but it work on Huawei G300 with Kitkat, but not work on Samsung Galaxy SII with JB.

When I set top margin for example to -1dp on SII is whole view out of display (same as i set negative margin with height of view), but view should be by 1dp upper.

Is there any way to use nagative margins correctly?

Thanks for advance

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && y < getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.trip_map_height) / 2) {
        photoSwitcher.setTranslationY(y);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) photoSwitcher.getLayoutParams();
        if (layoutParams != null) {
            layoutParams.topMargin = y * -1;
            Log.d("Scroll", "Top margin: " + layoutParams.topMargin);
            photoSwitcher.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            photoSwitcher.requestLayout();
        }
        else {
            Log.e("Scroll", "layout params null");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its a bad habbit to use negative margin.
For Reference link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673503/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-in-android

Comment: I highly recommended to use Padding instead of margin.

Comment: I know, but I don't know other way to narrow image from top.

Comment: which layout are you using ?

Comment: photoSwitcher is in RelativeLayout and RelativeLayout is in ScrollView

Comment: @ArslanAhmad margins and paddings are completly different beasts

Comment: @Vanama please follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334927/android-relativelayout-aligntop-doesnt-work

Comment: @ArslanAhmad I don't have any background setted.